# Which is "more open" on Christmas Day: Zurich or Milan?

Tags: zurich, milan, christmas

I'm planning a trip to Europe for the holiday season this year.  Our tentative itinerary is to start in Munich, stop by Zurich, and end in Milan (all by train).  There's an open question of whether or not we should spend Christmas Eve / Day in Zurich or Milan.

It's my understanding from the research I've done that both places will have sparse activities for us on holidays.  I would love to have a nice, high-end meal (under 150 EUR / person) at a restaurant for us to celebrate with, but which of the two cities would be best for an evening meal?  Are there any other activities a couple of tourists could enjoy before dinner?  Which city would be best for us to spend time in on Christmas Day?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The question is probably a little bit too general but should be still answerable. For the dinner meal on Christmas Day (i.e. Dec 25) your best bet in Zurich is probably to be a guest at a fancy-ish hotel that includes a good restaurant. Zurich at Christmas Eve (the 24) can be still quite festive. I don't know about Milan though.

Comment: @xngtng even in London most restaurants, including many in high end hotels, are closed on Christmas Eve and/or Christmas Day (and often for a few days before/after, as a lot of the staff which is from Eastern or Southern Europe return home for the holiday). I would be surprised if it was much better in Zürich, but I’ve never tried it there. I would also expect to pay a hefty premium. My recommendation is to call the restaurants you would like to go to. They will be able to tell if they will be open and possibly if there are any special rules (like a fixed, expensive menu).

Comment: Since Zurich / Switzerland is quite expensive in general, I'm not sure you would be able to get a "high-end meal under 150€" at all.

Comment: You will probably need to book well in advance, although the availability of services has improved in more cosmopolitan recent years, as many of the staff celebrate festival days other than Christmas, which is just another day to them.

Comment: Hmm, I figured 150 EUR would be a good price point... we've got New Year's Eve in Paris with a Michelin star for 120.  If there's anything in the ballpark we're open to it if Zurich is more expensive than Paris.